# What patterns could be observed in this quantum entanglement thought experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

Please see attached image below.

[image]
The DEVICE is beaming two streams of entangled particle pairs (B1 and B2) in opposite directions (e.g.: Particle no. 1 (p1) goes left, Particle no. 2 (p2) goes right, where p1 and p2 are making up an entangled particle pair).  Let us follow the left particle beam (B1) for now. When B1 encounters the Double Slit Apparatus (A1) in its way, an interference pattern will form on the Detector Screen (S1) behind.
There is a switchable Which-way Detector (D1) that can monitor Double Slit Apparatus (A1). If D1 is switched off, the interference pattern prevails; however, if D1 is active, the wave function collapses and draws a ballistic pattern over time.

**My questions are:**

1. what pattern is detected by S2 if D1 is active?
2. and what pattern emerges on S2 when it is turned off?

Thank you!

Comment: entangled on which state ?

Comment: @igael How does the state relate to the patterns detected on the screens?

Comment: The double slits won't care about the entanglement. You could correlate single photon detections on the screens between A and B... but this is just another quantum Rube Goldberg machine that teaches nothing about physics.

Comment: @Balázs : the following question is 'what is the relation between this entanglement and the 2 slits exp. ?'

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, the pattern detected at S2 will not depend on the detector D1.  Otherwise, this could be used for faster-than-light signalling, which is impossible within quantum mechanics.

Beyond that, what you will see at S2 will depend on which degree of freedom has been entangled.  Generally, one would expect to see an interference pattern, but if you manage to entangle a degree of freedom which relates to the slit taken by the photon, there will be no interference pattern.

Comment: What is the reason why S2 observations will not "depend" on D1 collapsing p1's superposition when determining which way it went? Why would its entangled pair p2 not show correlation with p1 when measured at S2?

Comment: The observation at site 2 will possibly depend on the *outcome* of the which-way measurement (if it is done), but not on the fact *whether* it is done. So there is correlation of *results*, but no causal dependence between actions.

Comment: Could you elaborate please how entanglement on different degrees of freedom in a pair of particles may produce different results on S2?

Comment: @Balázs If the degree of freedom which is entangled determines the slit taken, it will destroy the interference pattern, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 1):

When entangled photons are created in Bell-type experiments, it is their polarizations which are entangled. It is not clear to me that their positions or momenta are entangled in the same way. But anyway, engtanglement does not violate "no action at a distance" and in particular there is no way to see at location S1 what measurement is being made at location S2. Therefore it is clear that an interference pattern observed at location S2 cannot change according to how the photons are measured at location S1.

Comment: If there is no way to see at location S2 what measurement is being made at location S1, how can measurement correlations between the entangled particle pairs be established? In other words: how would you confirm that particles of the entangled pairs were in fact entangled?

Comment: In your experiment, you are assuming entanglement. With that understood, I am not aware that you can check for entanglement once you started the experiment.

Comment: @Balázs Correlation is not equal to causation.

Comment: @EdYablecki when one half of an entangled particle pair decoheres to a certain state, the other half is always found having (anti)correlated states. I won't be able to name the specific experiment that confirmed this, but this is kind of a fact (if I understand it right), which means the scientists had to have a way to measure both ends.

Comment: @Balázs, you may be mixing up entanglement and the observer effect. This is what the experiment is testing if photons that are entangled are also entangled for the observer effect. The answer is no, observer effect is not an entangle state, polarization is.

Comment: Note in quantum optics, the process known as spontaneous parametric down-conversion can be used (and routinely is used) to generate entanglement in all sorts of different degrees of freedom of a pair of photons including time-energy, position-momentum, angular position-angular momentum, polarization and any combination of one or more of the above depending on the experimental setup.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0409149.pdf

Answer (score -1):

If D1 is off on both sides will be interference pattern, may be shifted in phase.
If D1 is on there are no interference patterns on any side.

Comment: If D1 is on and position of p1 is known, question is , how strongly the entanglement determines position of p2  with reference to p1. if it is 100% correlation , so the result will be no interference pattern at all. Somewhat similar situation is at quantum eraser experiment. I assume that the system can be ideally adjusted to secure perfect symmetry of the slots.

Comment: An interesting experiment could be made to see how D1 affects direction of particle 2. If we remove double slit A2 we could observe how position on S2 changes when we turn D1 on and off.

Comment: In the last one results should be registered one by one to see the correlation. If it is 100% regarding position, or it may be partial as a function of the tiny angle between slits.